# Inject different data to same controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a controller that will have identical functionality to another by manage different data.  I am new to angularJS so I'm not exactly sure how to proceed. I've read about services and factories but have only seen examples of injecting the same data across different controllers instead of different data to the same controller.  Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

```
angular.module("myApp")
   .controller("AirlineController", function () {
       this.Airlines = getAirlines(); //some service call that will be ajax eventually      
   });

angular.module("myApp")
   .controller("CitiesController", function () {
       this.Cities = getCities();//some service call that will be ajax eventually
   });

angular.module("myApp")
   .controller("GenericController", function () {
       $('.selected-items-box').bind('click', function (e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
           $('.image-select-wrapper .list').toggle('slideDown');
       });

       $(document).bind('click', function () {
           $('.image-select-wrapper .list').slideUp();
       });

       this.ListObject = getAirlines();//this list should be populated from one of the other controllers

       this.toggleSelected = function (selectedItem) {
           angular.forEach(this.ListObject, function (ListItem) {
               ListItem == selectedItem ? ListItem.selected = true : ListItem.selected = false;
           });
       };

       this.getSelectedItem = function (item) {
           return item.selected;
       };
   });
```

Comment: why you are not using `.factory` which will return your data and then call it in your controller

Comment: from my understanding, if I use a factory I have to declare the data I am expecting within the controller, which means it's still hardcoded and does not allow dynamic data to be used in the GenericController.  If this is not the case I apologize for my ignorance, as I mentioned I'm new to angular.

Comment: here if you want data dynamic data then you will get that data in your factory then return it and by calling it in controller you can use it

Comment: so you're saying the factory will be able to retrieve both the airlines and the cities on queue and send it to the controller whenever I need one or the other?

Comment: if you want then I can share one `.factory` example with you, with small idea about how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function parameters to making a factory more versatile.

```
app.factory("getGeneric", function($http) {
    var apiUrl = "http:/my.com/api/"
    //Use function parameter
    return function (arg1) {
        //return promise
        return $http.get(apiUrl + arg1);
    }
});
```

Then in your controllers.

```
app.controller("AirlineController", function (getGeneric) {
     var vm = this;

     //use function parameter
     var airlinesPromise = getGeneric("Airlines"); //service returns promise

     airlinesPromise.then( function onFulfilled(response) {
         vm.Airlines = response.data;
     });     
});

app.controller("CitiesController", function (getGeneric) {
     var vm = this;

     //use function parameter
     var citiesPromise = getGeneric("Cities"); //service returns promise

     citiesPromise.then( function onFulfilled(response) {
         vm.Cities = response.data;
     });
});
```

Please notice that most servive APIs are asynchronous and do not return data immediately. The AngularJS `$http` service returns promises and data needs to be extracted from the promise with its `.then` method.

Another point is **make factories generic** and make controllers **lean and specific**. Controllers should be lean and specific to their HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try it and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly achieve that. You can have a factory/service that has the methods with parameters that you can pass from the controller. For example I have two controllers and one service that both the controllers are calling.

Based on the the parameter values passed, the service will return different set of data. I'm using the $scope but you can use this but the idea remains the same.

```
angular.module('SelectOptionModule')
    .controller('AirlineController', function ($scope, AirlineService) {
        $scope.Airline = AirlineService.GetAirLines("a")
    });

angular.module('SelectOptionModule')
    .controller('Airline2Controller', function ($scope, AirlineService) {
        $scope.Airline = AirlineService.GetAirLines("b")
    });

angular.module('SelectOptionModule')
    .factory('AirlineService', AirlineService);

function AirlineService() {
    function GetAirLines(value) {
        if (value == "a")
        {
            return [{ "Id" : "1", "Name" : "AA" } ]
        }

        if (value == "b") {
            return [{ "Id": "2", "Name": "Delta" }]
        }
    }

    return {
        GetAirLines: GetAirLines
    };
}
```

The View can be like to test this out.

```
<div ng-app='SelectOptionModule' >
    <div ng-controller="AirlineController">
        {{ Airline }}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Airline2Controller">
        {{ Airline }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try it and see how it goes